# Liquibase - generating a changelog for existing Sybase db

Tags: sybase, liquibase

I'm looking to set up Liquibase for a project with an existing Sybase db. I've tried running the following command:

```
lb --driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver \
   --classpath=C:\<home>\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\jtds\jtds\1.2.8\jtds-1.2.8.jar \
   --changeLogFile=testInitialChangelog.xml \
   --url="jdbc:jtds:sybase://<host>:<port>/<dbname>" \
   --username="<dbuser>" \
   --password="<dbpwd>" \
   --defaultSchemaName=<dbname> \
   --logLevel=debug \
generateChangeLog
```

It's not worked - well, it's produced an empty changelog. The output was:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\<home>
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Connected to <dbuser>@jdbc:jtds:sybase://<host>:<port>/<dbname>
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Not adjusting the auto commit mode; it is already true
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1498752444338 as a8b042e5c46068977523e7071dff7a0f
WARNING 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Did not find schema '<dbname>' to snapshot
INFO 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
INFO 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Can not use class liquibase.serializer.core.json.JsonChangeLogSerializer as a Liquibase service because org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath
INFO 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: testInitialChangelog.xml does not exist, creating
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: MissingObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.
structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core
.View
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: UnexpectedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.StoredProcedure    liqui
base.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.View    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core.
Sequence
DEBUG 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: ChangedObjectChangeGenerator type order:     liquibase.structure.core.Catalog    liquibase.structure.core.ForeignKey    liquibase.structure.core.Schema    liquibase.structure.core.Sequence    liquibase.struc
ture.core.StoredProcedure    liquibase.structure.core.Table    liquibase.structure.core.Column    liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey    liquibase.structure.core.UniqueConstraint    liquibase.structure.core.Index    liquibase.structure.core
.View
Liquibase 'generateChangeLog' Successful
```

Comment: I think the line in the output that says "WARNING 29/06/17 17:07: liquibase: Did not find schema '<dbname>' to snapshot" is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it was quite simple - the `--defaultSchemaName=` parameter. Set to `defaultSchemaName=dbo` and it worked.